# R equivalent of Python 'pass' statement

Tags: r

Python has a [`pass` statement](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_pass_statement.htm), a null operation, which can be a useful placeholder before code is complete, for example in Python:

```
def example_function():
    pass
    # stuff to do here
```

Is there an equivalent in R? Thank you.

Comment: Python offers `pass` because compound statements *require* a block, but for some use-cases it is useful to have that block not do anything (`except SomeException: pass`). Does R require that statements have a body?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just have an empty function body:

```
foo = function(){
 }
```

You should probably also add a comment, and a warning maybe?

```
foo = function(){
# write this tomorrow
 warning("You ran foo and I havent written it yet")
}
```

Same thing with an `if` expression:

```
if(x==1){
  # do this bit later
  }else{
  message("x isnt 1")
}
```

Comment: this yields a NULL printed in the console. Can I avoid that? Thanks-

Comment: @YZhang wrap the function call in 'invisible(your_function)'

Comment: thank you @jkd! Putting `invisible` when calling the function sounds not ideal - you don't remember which function is empty, and a function may print something useful and also has a empty section. Is there an alternative that I can do in the definition of the function and specifically to the empty section? Thank you

Comment: @YZhang you could do something meaningless in the function like `i <- 0`, `NULL` is not printed on function call and `i` doesn't exists outside of the scope of your function... I had no better idea

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want `NULL` returned,and you don't want to wrap your function call with `invisible()`, you can include `invisible()` **inside** of the function body. This returns nothing:

```
my_func  <- function(x){
  invisible()
}
my_func(100)
```